# Functions.js file "Not a WebHook" webhookType

Tags: azure-functions

I cannot see any samples or documentation for the WebHookType. In the UI I can set it to "Not a WebHook" and want to do this in the functions.js, all samples seem to be "genericJson".

```
"webHookType": "genericJson"
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so I went into Function App settings for the Azure Function and then to Go to App Service Settings and then opened up Tools and went to Kudu. I could navigate to the functions.js file and see what the file looked it.

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "webHookType": "",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```