# Handling application/x-www-form-urlencoded posts

Tags: azure-functions

Trying to integrate with Slack that sends outgoing webhooks as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not as an expected `application/json`. Any way to allow Azure Fucntions to accept a webhook (C#) that would process `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441759/functions-js-file-not-a-webhook-webhooktype) helped me.
Azure Functions can support 3 types of webhooks

1. Generic JSON
2. GitHub
3. Slack

`functions.json` file responsible for bindings can be manipulated directly

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

or via UI

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in your related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949872/configure-slack-authentication-token) not all of the various ASP.NET WebHook receivers are handled fully yet in Functions. We're currently only handling **application/json** WebHooks well at the moment, but not all of the other Content-Types. I've logged a new issue in our repo [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/317) to track this.

We'll address those issues soon. Feel free to track the progress and chime in more in our issues list. Thanks :)