# How do I configure my Android phone to send images to Twilio via MMS?

Tags: android, twilio, mms

Using my Android phone, I want to share an image via MMS to a Twilio phone number and be able to extract the images via code.

I have set up a Function App to capture the message, as per my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972655/how-do-i-set-up-a-function-app-to-extract-data-from-media-type-application-x-ww/47973449#47973449)

I am surprised however to find that the message contains the following values

```
NumMedia = 0
Body = 
"You+have+a+new+MMS+Picture+or+Video+Message.+To+view+your+message%2C+go+to+http%3A%2F%2Ftelstra.com%2Fmmsview   etc
```

I was hoping that NumMedia would be 1 and that I would be able to iterate through a collection of images to extract.

I guess the issue is that I am not sending the mms via the Twilio API. Instead I am sending it via my phone directly.

How can I extract the pictures that I share via text message?
Does it depend on my phone carrier?

[Update]
I have no experience as an Android developer so I am preferring a no-code solution.

There is a  [Twilio support link](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181228-Why-do-my-messages-include-a-Twilio-URL-) that mention a Twilio URL, however I am receiving a Telstra URL

The phone is a [Samsung Galaxy J1 mini](http://www.samsung.com/au/support/model/SM-J105YZDAXSA)

Comment: checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/how-to-send-image-via-mms-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio advises this is because my Twilio number is not MMS capable. I need to try it with an MMS Capable number. This will need to be an international number at the moment.

[How to check if a Twilio number can send MMS messages](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223182808-How-to-check-if-a-Twilio-number-can-send-MMS-messages)

[Trial account restrictions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136107-How-does-Twilio-s-Free-Trial-work-)

[Guidelines for Australia](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/au)